# R httr post with headers

Tags: python, r, httr

I have the following request in Python. How can I rewrite this in `R`'s `httr` package?

The thing I'm not sure about is how to translate the `json` and `tuple` equivalent in R.

```
import requests

cookies = {}

headers = {
    'Host': 'mysejahtera.malaysia.gov.my',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Length': '77',
    'Authorization': 'Basic N0ZFRkRCMTMtN0Q2MC00NEQxLUE5MTctM0',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-MY;q=1, ms-MY;q=0.9',
    'User-Agent': 'MySejahtera/1.0.36 (iPhone; iOS 14.6; Scale/2.00)',
}

params = (
    ('type', 'search'),
)

data = '[{"lat":3.003090,"lng":101.678300,"classification":"LOW_RISK_NS"}]'

response = requests.post('https://mysejahtera.malaysia.gov.my/register/api/nearby/hotspots', headers=headers, params=params, cookies=cookies, data=data)
response.json()
```

Here's an attempt. But still gives out `400` bad request

```
POST("https://mysejahtera.malaysia.gov.my/register/api/nearby/hotspots?type=search",
     body = list(lat = 3.003090, lng = 101.678300, classification = 'LOW_RISK_NS'), 
     add_headers(Host= 'mysejahtera.malaysia.gov.my',
                 Accept= 'application/json',
                 Connection= 'keep-alive',
                 `Content-Length`= '77',
                 Authorization= 'Basic N0ZFRkRCMTMtN0Q2MC00NEQxLUE5MTctM0',
                 `Content-Type`= 'application/json',
                 `Accept-Language`= 'en-MY;q=1, ms-MY;q=0.9',
                 `User-Agent`= 'MySejahtera/1.0.36 (iPhone; iOS 14.6; Scale/2.00)'), verbose())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here seemed to be to construct the data as a list of a named list so that it is encoded to json as the API expects.

Note, most of the supplied headers proved unnecessary (or are automatically generated by `httr`) in order to retrieve the desired response.

```r
library(httr)

# data as list of named list
data <- list(
  list(
    lat = 3.003090,
    lng = 101.678300,
    classification = "LOW_RISK_NS"
  )
)

params <- list(type = "search")

response <- POST("https://mysejahtera.malaysia.gov.my/register/api/nearby/hotspots",
                 query = params,
                 body = data, 
                 add_headers(Authorization = "Basic N0ZFRkRCMTMtN0Q2MC00NEQxLUE5MTctM0"),
                 encode = "json"
)
content(response)
#> $hotSpots
#> list()
#> 
#> $zoneType
#> [1] "RED"
#> 
#> $messages
#> $messages$ms_MY
#> [1] "Hai {name}, terdapat 21 kes COVID-19 dalam lingkungan radius 1km dari lokasi ini yang dilaporkan dalam masa 14 hari yang lepas."
#> 
#> $messages$en_US
#> [1] "Hi {name}, there have been 21 reported case(s) of COVID-19 within a 1km radius from your searched location in the last 14 days."
#> 
#> 
#> $note
#> NULL
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

## Some Explanation

### JSON from List vs List of List

See here the difference (i.e., the addition of square brackets) in the resulting strings of json between a named list and a list of a named list:

```r
data <- list(lat = 3, lng = 101, class = "LOW")

# list
jsonlite::toJSON(data)
#> {"lat":[3],"lng":[101],"class":["LOW"]}

# list of a named list
jsonlite::toJSON(list(data))
#> [{"lat":[3],"lng":[101],"class":["LOW"]}]
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

### Even Simpler Approach

Here I do more of the encoding work myself rather than letting `httr` take care of it as in the answer above.

Note that the square brackets surrounding the values are now missing as compared to the second (list of list) json string above. This is representative of the "unboxing" `httr` does.

```r
library(httr)

response <- POST("https://mysejahtera.malaysia.gov.my/register/api/nearby/hotspots?type=search",
                 body = '[{"lat":3.003090,"lng":101.678300,"classification":"LOW_RISK_NS"}]', 
                 add_headers(Authorization = "Basic N0ZFRkRCMTMtN0Q2MC00NEQxLUE5MTctM0",
                             "Content-Type" = "application/json")
)
content(response)
#> $hotSpots
#> list()
#> 
#> $zoneType
#> [1] "RED"
#> 
#> $messages
#> $messages$ms_MY
#> [1] "Hai {name}, terdapat 22 kes COVID-19 dalam lingkungan radius 1km dari lokasi ini yang dilaporkan dalam masa 14 hari yang lepas."
#> 
#> $messages$en_US
#> [1] "Hi {name}, there have been 22 reported case(s) of COVID-19 within a 1km radius from your searched location in the last 14 days."
#> 
#> 
#> $note
#> NULL
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I was suspecting the same about the `list of list` but couldn't really validate and understand why. I would really appreciate if you can point me to some resources to learn more about using R and web tech like this. I went through the vignette and documentation but couldn't really get this kind of explanation.

Comment: I agree that the httr documentation is a bit opaque and the vignettes are limited in scope. I suppose they were going for simplicity because httr is based on [curl](https://curl.se/) which is heavily documented. The better you understand curl, the easier it becomes to figure out httr.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I set the input values inside a `list()` or a vector `c()` when web scraping with R.

httr's `POST()` accepts JSON as the body as well, as you can see on the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/httr/versions/1.4.2/topics/POST).

Your code would most likely look like this:

```
library(httr)

cookies <- c()

headers <- c('Host' = 'mysejahtera.malaysia.gov.my',
             'Accept' = 'application/json',
             'Connection' = 'keep-alive',
             'Content-Length' = '77',
             'Authorization' = 'Basic N0ZFRkRCMTMtN0Q2MC00NEQxLUE5MTctM0',
             'Content-Type' = 'application/json',
             'Accept-Language' = 'en-MY;q=1, ms-MY;q=0.9',
             'User-Agent' = 'MySejahtera/1.0.36 (iPhone; iOS 14.6; Scale/2.00)')

data <- list("type" = "search",
             "lat" = 3.003090,
             "lng" = 101.678300,
             "classification" = "LOW_RISK_NS")

response = POST("https://mysejahtera.malaysia.gov.my/register/api/nearby/hotspots",
                body = data,
                add_headers(.headers = headers))
```

I have incorporated the `params` into the `body` and I have removed the cookies, because they throw an error when they are empty.

The status code is still 400, which might indicate the need for the inclusion of other variables in the request.

Comment: `Error in request(headers = c(..., .headers)) : 
  is.character(headers) is not TRUE` it expects `character` instead of `list`

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the headers in a `c()` instead of a `list()`?

Comment: if I modify the `list()` from for the `headers` to `c()`, i will get a bad request 400

Comment: Can you give me a real-life example to test?

Comment: I have updated the code on the post accordingly. Please see if it works

Comment: thanks but unfortunately I'm getting 400 bad request still. I updated your lat lng and classification as well.

Comment: I think you're missing the `param` part

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233749/discussion-between-afiq-johari-and-paulo-schau-guerra).

Comment: 401 is authorization error. But here it is 400 which suggest some issues with the syntax. You can try running the Python code, it doesn't request for any user/pwd

Comment: I suspect the issue is with the `data` list. In `Python`, `data` is submitted as a `list` of `list`. But in your R solution, the `data` is written as a `list` of `string`.